# Are there Ubuntu User Experience Tests conducted. Are they open source and if so where can I find the data? any format accepted

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

I've tried searching related topics but nothing has satisfied my question

[Old Article is top google search](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/user-testing-of-unity-reveals-some-surprising-results)

[Older Blog referencing Scientific Method](https://design.canonical.com/2010/11/usability-testing-of-unity/)

There are plenty more examples of articles / links but nothing concrete.

I'd like to analyse the data myself and see if there is any stastically valid tests conducted at all.

I love Ubuntu, but find the Mac as it's a work machine is becoming my default OS

Thanks in advance to anyone who may point me in the right direction!

Comment: AskUbuntu is not affiliated with Canonical.

Comment: @CelticWarrior we are to some extent. Canonical lets us use the Ubuntu trademarks and officially recognizes us as a support forum in Ubuntu products and websites.

Comment: @muru However, *we* cannot request the information OP wants from Canonical.

Comment: @CelticWarrior: However, we can either 1) provide links to the info if public or 2) say that the data isn't available publicly.